# Kafka Streams: Custom TimestampExtractor for aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am building a pretty straightforward KafkaStreams demo application, to test a use case.

I am not able to upgrade the Kafka broker I am using (which is currently on version 0.10.0), and there are several messages written by a pre-0.10.0 Producer, so I am using a custom TimestampExtractor, which I add as a default to the config in the beginning of my main class:

```
config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericRecordTimestampExtractor.class);
```

When consuming from my source topic, this works perfectly fine. But when using an aggregation operator, I run into an exception **because the `FailOnInvalidTimestamp` implementation of `TimestampExtractor` is used instead of the custom implementation when consuming from the internal aggregation topic**.

The code of the Streams app looks something like this:

```
...

KStream<String, MyValueClass> clickStream = streamsBuilder
              .stream("mytopic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), valueClassSerde));

KTable<Windowed<Long>, Long> clicksByCustomerId = clickStream
              .map(((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.getId(), value)))
              .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.Long(), valueClassSerde))
              .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)))
              .count();
...
```

The Exception I'm encountering is the following:

```
    Exception in thread "click-aggregator-b9d77f2e-0263-4fa3-bec4-e48d4d6602ab-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: 
Input record ConsumerRecord(topic = click-aggregator-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000002-repartition, partition = 9, offset = 0, CreateTime = -1, serialized key size = 8, serialized value size = 652, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = 11230, value = org.example.MyValueClass@2a3f2ea2) has invalid (negative) timestamp. 
Possibly because a pre-0.10 producer client was used to write this record to Kafka without embedding a timestamp, or because the input topic was created before upgrading the Kafka cluster to 0.10+. Use a different TimestampExtractor to process this data.
```

---

Now the question is: Is there any way I can make Kafka Streams use the custom `TimestampExtractor` when reading from the internal aggregation topic (optimally while still using the Streams DSL)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the timestamp extractor (as of `v1.0.0`). This is not allowed for correctness reasons.

But I am really wondering, how a record with timestamp -1 is written into this topic in the first place. Kafka Streams uses the timestamp that was provided by your custom extractor when writing the record. Also note, that `KafkaProducer` does not allow to write records with negative timestamp.

Thus, the only explanation I can think of is that some other producer did write into the repartitioning topic -- and this is not allowed... Only Kafka Streams should write into the repartioning topic.

I guess, you will need to delete this topic and let Kafka Streams recreate it to get back into a clean state.

From the discussion/comment of the other answer:

> You need 0.10+ format to work with Kafka Streams. If you upgrade your brokers and keep 0.9 format or older, Kafka Streams might not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known issue :-). I have the same problem with old clients in the projects which are still using older Kafka clients like 0.9 and also when communicating with some "not certified" .NET clients.

Therefore I wrote dedicated class:

```
public class MyTimestampExtractor implements TimestampExtractor {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger( MyTimestampExtractor.class );

    @Override
    public long extract ( ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord, long previousTimestamp ) {
        final long timestamp = consumerRecord.timestamp();

        if ( timestamp < 0 ) {
            final String msg = consumerRecord.toString().trim();
            LOG.warn( "Record has wrong Kafka timestamp: {}. It will be patched with local timestamp. Details: {}", timestamp, msg );
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

When there are many messages you may skip logging, as it may flood.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Matthias' answer I double checked everything and the cause of the issue were incompatible versions between the Kafka Broker and the Kafka Streams app. <strike>I was stupid enough to use Kafka Streams 1.0.0 with a 0.10.1.1 Broker, which is clearly stated as incompatible in the Kafka Wiki [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix).</strike>

Edit (thx to Matthias): The actual cause of the problem was the fact, that the log format used by our 0.10.1.x broker was still 0.9.0.x, which is incompatible with Kafka Streams.

Comment: That does not sound correct -- the information in the wiki page seems to be incorrect (I'll update it). Streams API 1.0.0 is compatible with 0.10.1.1 brokers. Compare: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/upgrade-guide.html#compatibility

Comment: That is strange. When I downgraded the kafka-clients and kafka-streams libraries to 0.10.1.1 (and made the obvious API changes i.e. KStreamsBuilder instead of StreamsBuilder etc.) the program runs just fine. Could this be a bug? What I am seeing is, that the RecordQueue of the aggregation topic uses FailOnInvalidTimestamp in the 1.0.0 version. It then fails when calling timestampExtractor#extract in the addRawRecords method. In 0.10.1.1 the timestamp extractor is not a field in RecordQueue but gets passed as a parameter to addRawRecords, and has the correct type (my custom extractor).

Comment: There was an update in 1.0 release (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4785) -- however, I still don't understand how a negative timestamp can end-up in the topic -- what log format version do you use? Kafka Streams required 0.10 brokers (ie, 0.10 log format to store timestamps in the intermediate topics).

Comment: Hi Matthias, the log.message.format.version property is still set to 0.9.0.X. This seems wrong to me, but I was not involved in upgrading the broker to 0.10.1.1 which happenend quite some time ago.

Comment: So this is obviously the problem! Thanks for your input! :)

Comment: Yes. You need 0.10+ format to work with Kafka Streams.